# jquery multipe events with one ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, func

I have two jQuery events using the same ajax function

```
$(document).on("focus blur change keyup", "#bc", function () {
    $.ajax({
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    });
});


$(document).on("change", ".op", function () {
    $.ajax({
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    });
});
```

is there a way of combining the two without having to repeat the ajax code?

Comment: You can put your XXXXXXXXXX code into a function and then call it from ajax both times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
function x(){
    $.ajax({
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    });
}

$(document).on("change", ".op", x); 

$(document).on("focus blur change keyup", "#bc", x);
```